# IOS 5 CoreData Sorting by a string property doesn't work

Tags: ios, string, sorting, core-data

I have an attribute `imageName` which is a **string** 
and set to be **indexed**.

I'm trying to **sort** my fetch result **by** this `imageName`

It works only on the first time I enter the viewController that makes this fetch.
On the next time it seems like the results are sorted arbitrarily (even though it is poped from UINavigationController and recreated).

The strings are of the form: `hair001.png`, `hair002.png`, `hair003.png` ,...

Here is how I perform the fetch:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"AvProperty"];

request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type = %d && isPrototype=%@",type,[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"imageName" ascending:YES]]; 

NSError *error;
NSArray *properties = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your view controller is updated appropriately when it reappears. In `viewWillAppear` you could send your fetched results controller a `performFetch:` message to refresh your table view.